# How do I get the index of a specific Paragraph in a Paragraph Collection in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm extracting some text from a series of INDD files using a script. I have a paragraph from a `findGrep()` result, and I'd like to start a `for` loop at this paragraph in the `parentStory` paragraph collection:

```
var paragraph = findGrep()[0].paragraphs[0];
var parentStory = paragraph.parentStory.paragraphs;
for (var x = paragraph.index; x < parentStory.length; x++) {...}
```

I realize that `Paragraphs` have an index property, but the value of `paragraph.index` is wildly out of the appropriate range (ie, 1188, 984, ect...).

What am I missing here?

Comment: The parent of all text-related objects is `Text`; `Line`, `Word`, and even `Paragraph` are thin wrappers around this. The "index" of all of these items is simply the index of their first character, offset from the start of the text. Does that help you?

Comment: @Jongware That does help! Looks like I was approaching the problem from the wrong direction. I'll probably abstract this into a `Paragraph.next()` method for use in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a paragraph p, its first insertionPoint is

ip = p.insertionPoints[0];

and the index of that would be

ip.index;

So, if you've got a handle on the parent story, s, to get to paragraph p, you could do:

s.insertionPoints[ip.index].paragraphs[0];

Regarding a "paragraph next" method: You can always get the next paragraph of any given paragraph using

myParagraph.insertionPoints[-1].paragraphs[0];

Because the last insertionPoint of any paragraph is the first insertionPoint of the next.